# How to replace null with n/a in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code which returns an `integer` datatype, else `null`. Now for `null` values, I want to replace it with `'N/A'`. I tried to use **replace** but it doesn't change.

Sample output:

```
2014-FW RTW1005F4   NULL
```

Code:

```
select a.Season_id,a.Style_id,
  ( case when ((( a.Content_class = 'ART' and a.Mat_ref_id in (select  Mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type='EMB'))))
       then count(a.Mat_ref_id)
    else null
  end ) as Embro
from iPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL a
inner join iPLEXMAT_MATERIAL_PARM b on b.Mat_ref_id = a.Mat_ref_id
where b.artwrk_type is not null and a.Style_id = 'RTW1005F4' 
group by a.Season_id,a.Style_id,a.Content_class,a.Mat_ref_id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results woudl really help.

Comment: You can't return 'n/a' as an integer datatype - you either have to convert your numbers to a string OR a better approach is to format this in the application.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return `'N/A'`, then you have to convert the value to a string:

```
(case when a.Content_class = 'ART' and
           a.Mat_ref_id in (select  Mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type = 'EMB')
      then convert(varchar(255), count(a.Mat_ref_id))
      else 'N/A'
 end) as Embro
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce`

```
Select coalesce(column,'n/a')
```

It will return n/a when the column value is null but for that column has to be string type as your column is int so convert it on string type

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select a.Season_id,a.Style_id,
  ISNULL(( case when ((( a.Content_class = 'ART' and a.Mat_ref_id in (select  Mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type='EMB'))))
       then count(a.Mat_ref_id)
    else null
  end ),'N/A') as Embro
from iPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL a
inner join iPLEXMAT_MATERIAL_PARM b on b.Mat_ref_id = a.Mat_ref_id
where b.artwrk_type is not null and a.Style_id = 'RTW1005F4' 
group by a.Season_id,a.Style_id,a.Content_class,a.Mat_ref_id
```